# How to get a logistic regression model

Tags: r

I have trouble getting the logistic regression model. I wrote some codes like this but I am not sure they are the right ones. Should I factor 'sex'?

```
donner <- read.csv("~/Desktop/donner.txt", sep="")
sex = donner$sex
sexcode = ifelse(sex=='F', 1, 0)
mod5 = glm(donner$survivorship ~ sexcode+donner$age, family = "binomial")
summary(mod5)
```

Moreover, I have trouble getting the formula for the estimated curve by using `π^=P^(survivorship=1|age,sex)=` and how can I get the fitted male model？

Here is part of the `data(sex:1=male,0=female & survivorship : 1 = survived, 0 = dead)`

[image]

Comment: Check `?glm` for the correct usage. It has to be something like `glm(survivorship ~ sexcode + age, data=donner, family = "binomial")`, where all the variables in the formula are part of the dataframe and not individual vectors.

Comment: @KarthikArumugham It works, thank you!